# Disk performance results with iostat

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I'm trying to measure HDD performance using iostat in order to decide how to assign disk resources for Docker containers. For this i need write and read speed and number of I/O performed per second. Unfortunately, the results are very low and I'm wondering if i'm doing something wrong.

```
tomek@laptop:~$ iostat -dx -m /dev/sdb
Linux 4.13.0-32-generic (laptop)    14.02.2018  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
sdb              0,04    0,10      0,00      0,01     0,00     0,02   0,50  20,12    8,11   41,63   0,00    28,02    61,27  12,36   0,16
```

Can those results be that low? Or maybe I'm using wrong options? This drive is containing /home directory, system is installed on sda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iostat without interval and counts parameter shows the overall statistics since boot time so that the average values are leveled down by quiet times.

Use `iostat <options> 10 5` to get 5 measurements of 10 seconds each to show your current activity.